# MySQL, IFNULL(), COALESCE() on String not replacing

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, coalesce, ifnull

My statement should replace every **empty** `title_column` with **'no name'**, but it doesn't:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(main_table.title_column, 'no name') AS title
FROM main_table;
```

`IFNULL()` behaves the same way.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Could it be you're seeing empty string values instead of null values?

Comment: obviously, thats the case. and another user posted the solution...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`COALESCE` and `IFNULL` substitute only `NULL` values, your table seem to contain empty strings:

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(NULLIF(main_table.title_column, ''), 'no name') AS title
FROM main_table;
```

Answer (score 4):

In MySQL a `NULL` string and an empty (`''`) string are not the same thing.

You have a few options, for consistency I use CASE...

```
CASE WHEN main_table.title_column = '' THEN 'no name' ELSE main_table.title_column END
```

Other options could be the COALESCE(NULLIF()) shown on another answer *(which uses NULLIF() to turn empty strings into NULLs and then uses coalesce as you wanted to)*.

Or possibly just IIF() to shorten the CASE statement...

```
IIF(main_table.title_column = '', 'no name', main_table.title_column)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer a functional way of giving solutions
you can always use this:

```
DELIMITER $$
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Note: add your server side comments to remember what this routine does on your Api
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `IfNullOrEmpty`$$
CREATE FUNCTION `IfNullOrEmpty`(s TEXT, value TEXT) RETURNS TEXT
NOT DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN

IF ( (s is null) OR (trim(s) = '')  ) THEN
    return value;
END IF;
return s;    
END$$
```

Usage:

```
SELECT IfNullOrEmpty(t.FieldName,'No Name Given') as Name FROM cms_Table t
```

Answer (score 1):

used this solution for MySql,

```
SELECT IF((TRIM(main_table.title_column) = ''),'no name', COALESCE(main_table.title_column, 'no name')) AS title FROM main_table
```